# how to generate an array like [0.001, 0.1, 1,10]

Tags: python-3.x

Everyone, I am new to python.
how can I generate an array like `[0.001, 0.1, 1,10]`?

I tried

```
rlt = linspace(0.001, 0.1, 10)
```

But the above code only got points in equal space

Comment: Are you trying to generate a list of powers  of 10?

Comment: Can you clarify what it's supposed to do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sequence = [ ]
for i in range(-3, 1):
    sequence.append(10**i)
print(sequence)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use numpy package on python

> NumPy is a Python library that provides a simple yet powerful data
> structure: the n-dimensional array. This is the foundation on which
> almost all the power of Python's data science toolkit is built, and
> learning NumPy is the first step on any Python data scientist's
> journey

Here's the link for further info and tutorial
[Link](https://numpy.org/)
[Link2](https://realpython.com/numpy-tutorial/#:%7E:text=NumPy%20is%20a%20Python%20library,any%20Python%20data%20scientist%27s%20journey.)

Answer (score 0):

Just do `arr = [0.001, 0.1, 1,10]`. Simple. This will be an array with 4 values. I guess this is what you want.